# Как применить array_count_values для многомерного массива?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив:

```
Array ( 
 [0] => Array ( 
   [user] => 43324353, 
   [like] => 34 
 ) 
 [1] => Array ( 
   [user] => 3424453,
   [like] => 24 
 ) 
 [2] => Array (
   [user] => 43324353,
   [like] => 24
 ) 
)
```

Как вывести наиболее встречаемого юзера [user] и сумму его всех лайков [Like]

```
array (
  [user] => 43324353
  [like] => 58
)
```

Comment: Не использовать функцию array_**count**_values если нам надо **суммировать** значения и поэтому написать примитивный цикл руками?

Comment: А если эти данные приходят из БД, то получить искомую сумму прямо в запросе

Comment: @Ипатьев данные не из бд приходят. А может как-то получить сначала в таком видел:
Array ( 
 [0] => Array ( 
   [user] => 43324353, 
   [like] => 34 
 ) 
 [1] => Array (
   [user] => 43324353,
   [like] => 24
 ) 
)
А потом как-то пробигаться и суммировать

Comment: Может. Ты вообще с таким понятием как "цикл" знаком?

Comment: Только удобнее, наверное, будет такой: Array ( 43324353 => 58, 3424453 => 24 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так не посчитать, единственный выход это писать свою функцию,могу предложить свой вариант, но он не идеальный, у меня функция проходится 2 раза по исходному массиву, можно сделать чтобы было всё в 1 цикле, тут уже как пожелаете:

```
function array_count_user_likes($array = []) {
    //Проверка на то, есть ли вообще данные в массиве
    if (empty($array)) {
        return [
            'user' => 0,
            'like' => 0
        ];
    }

    $out = [];
    foreach ($array as $key => $value){
        if (array_key_exists($value['user'], $out) ) {
            $out[$value['user']]++;
        } else {
            $out[$value['user']] = 1;
        }
    }

    //Проверка на то, есть ли вообще данные в массиве
    if (empty($out)) {
        return [
            'user' => 0,
            'like' => 0
        ];
    }

    //array_keys($out, max($out)) - может быть что у нескольких пользователей одинаковое количество лайков, то будет в массиве несколько значений, мы берем только первое
    $user_id = array_keys($out, max($out))[0];

    $likes = 0;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['user'] == $user_id) {
            $likes += $value['like'];
        }
    }

    return [
        'user' => $user_id,
        'like' => $likes
    ];
}
```

Использование:

```
$result = array_count_user_likes($data);
```

Comment: Все-таки меня поражает, насколько же любят пользователи похапе написать немеряную кучу кода абсолютно на пустом месте.

Comment: Писал бы для себя было в 2 раза меньше строк, но т.к. пишу для другого человека пытался расписать всё, и что в этом плохого? И при чем тут пхп вообще?

Comment: при том что только пыхеры обожают развозить турусы на колесах, по 5 раз перебирать один и тот же массив и писать по 10 раз абсолютно одинаковые куски кода. Такое ощущение что пара веков развития науки программирования прошли мимо них.

Answer (score 3):

Лично мне все-таки кажется что для подобных задач всегда достаточно одного цикла и одной сортировки.

```
$count = [];
$sum = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value){
    if (!array_key_exists($value['user'], $count) ) {
        $count[$value['user']] = 0;
        $sum[$value['user']] = 0;
    }
    $count[$value['user']] += 1;
    $sum[$value['user']] += $value['like'];
}
arsort($count);
$user = key($count);
$likes = $sum[$user];
```

Comment: я бы утомился столько раз писать `$value['user']` :)

Comment: Вот прям моя мысль! Но строчку сэкономить хотелось больше :)

Comment: @Ипатьев Все хорошо, но почему-то сумму полей LIKE не выводит, не могу разобраться почему(

Comment: @Ипатьев, т.е. оскорблять людей, которые хуже тебя это нормально? Кто-то говорил, что я хочу стать программистом? Что-то ни одного слова я об этом не видел,зато шквал гнева получил. Ну на этом спасибо, думаю из тебя вышел хороший программист)

Comment: @Ипатьев, кстати и за критику спасибо, понял в чем проблема была

Comment: Есть решение покороче =)

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам надо только наибольшее количество пользователей можно решить так: используем  [array_column](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-column.php) и как Вы написали  `array_count_values`.Ваш массив:

```
$users = [
    [
        "user" => 43324353,
        "likes" => 34
    ],
    [
        "user" => 3424453,
        "likes" => 24
    ],
    [
        "user" => 43324353,
        "likes" => 24
    ],
];
```

Выбираем колонку и выводим массив

```
$usersId = array_column($users, 'user');
$popularUser = array_count_values($usersId);
```

Если Вам нужно создать результирующий, отсортированный  массив, то реализация может выглядеть такой:

```
$usersId = array_column($users, 'user');
$popularUser = array_count_values($usersId);

$popular = [];
foreach ($popularUser as $key => $value) {

    foreach($users as $userKey => $user) {
        if($user['user'] == $key) {
            $user['count'] = $value;
            $popular[] = $user;
            break;
        }
    }

}

usort($popular, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['count'] < $b['count'];
});

var_dump($popular);
```

Можно реализовать внутренними функциями php без циклов, например ([array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-reduce.php)):

```
$prev = 0;

sort($users);

$test = array_reduce($users, function($carry, $item) use (&$prev)  {

    if(empty($carry)) {
      $item['count'] = 1;
      return [$item];
    } else if($item['user'] == $carry[$prev]['user']) {
      $carry[$prev]['count']++;
    } else  {
        $item['count'] = 1;
        $carry[] = $item;
        $prev++;
    }

    return $carry;
});

usort($test, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['count'] < $b['count'];
});

var_dump($test);
```

Comment: Мне особенно нравится утверждение "внутренними функциями без циклов" :)

Comment: Но по сравнению с первым вариантом, который использует аж 4 цикла, это, конечно, прорыв.

Comment: @Ипатьев я имел ввиду что циклы лежат на уровне php

Comment: зачем вам в первом варианте двойной цикл, если нужно вывести только одного самого популярного?

Comment: @teran есть вариант когда несколько будут популярными, допустим повторяться по 2 раза 3424453 и 43324353, поэтому лучше сделать отсортированный массив

Answer (score 0):

Поставленная задача имеет следующее решение:

```
$a2d = [
    [ 'user' => 43324353, 'like' => 34 ],
    [ 'user' => 3424453, 'like' => 24 ],
    [ 'user' => 43324353, 'like' => 24 ] ];
$monster = [];
array_walk($a2d,function($value)use(&$monster){
    $monster = array_merge($monster, array_fill(0, $value['like'], $value['user']));
});
$monster_count_values = array_count_values($monster);
$key = array_flip($monster_count_values)[max($monster_count_values)];
var_dump([$key => $monster_count_values[$key]]);
```

Результат:

```
C:\wamp64\www\2017\17_04_06_array_monster\index.php:12:
array (size=1)
  43324353 => int 58
```

<s>Странно, что никто не догадался...</s>

P.S. Иногда шутки приходится объяснять.

1. Вариант с размножением записей - это гротескная реакция на ужасную постановку задачи (не следует навязывать другим то, что не работает у тебя). Хотя при небольшом количестве лайков никто этого не заметит.
2. Профессиональные программисты пропитались идеями языков типа java, в которых для массивов есть только бинарный поиск, сортировка и немножко тривиальщины. Но до максимума следовало додуматься даже им.
3. Идея с флипом на самом деле малозатратна, поскольку не использует хэш-функцию. Зато позволяет использовать встроенную функцию максимума, оптимизированную для массивов.
4. Разговоры про оптимизацию на PHP бессмысленны, потому что его сущность (Personal Home Page) заложена в фундаментальные конструкции языка. Нравятся ассоциативные массивы - используешь, не нравится скорость - переходишь на другой язык.

Comment: Краткость не всегда означает оптимальность. Я здесь вижу как минимум три цикла, не говоря уже о функции array_merge, которая реализует [алгоритм маляра Шлёмы](http://russian.joelonsoftware.com/articles/backtobasics.html)

Comment: @Ипатьев А следовало увидеть офтопик =)

Comment: Я понял, тебе пообщаться не с кем. Извини, но мне не интересно.

Comment: @Ипатьев Тогда всерьёз: зачем сортировка вместо максимума?